# Kafka Transforms insert field into message value

Tags: apache-kafka, solr, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to use Kafka [Transforms InsertField](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html#insertfield) to add a new field into an existing field's message? I'm using [kafka-connect-solr](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-solr) and I'm trying to find a way to upate a solr collection that will contain information from 2 different but related topics i.e.

topic 1 -

```
{
  "foo": "example", 
  "bar": 1
  "id": 10
}
```

topic 2 -

```
{
  "baz":2
  "id": 10
}
```

Topic 1 will index into solr but topic 2 rather than appending the baz field will overwrite everything and the baz field along with the id will be the only thing remaining.

This overwrite mechanism is a behaviour of solr, to append rather than overwrite the **add** field should be used but I'm not sure if its possible to insert this field using kafka transforms.

Outcome I'm trying to achieve from topic 2 above to this -

```
{
  "baz": 
    {
      "add": [2]
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to join the 2 topics together to index all at once but this approach isn't ideal for me due to the amount of data. I'm starting to think that a custom Kafka transform may be the correct approach.

Comment: `InsertField` can only add primitives, not maps/objects or arrays and a custom transform wouldn't be able to refer to data from more than one topic

Comment: If each topic contained the `baz` field though wouldn't a custom transform work for that approach? I was thinking of having a specific broker only looking for topics that would require updates to solr, the custom transform would then insert the add syntax into the field value

Comment: You could modify an existing field with a transform, sure, but you shouldn't make your transform depend on an external source such as consuming from another topic

Comment: Understood. Rather than making it field-specific I was going to take the approach of allowing multiple fields to be passed through in the transform along with append of the desired message value  i.e. `"foo":"add", "bar":"remove"`. I essentially need something like the hoist field but rather than perform the action on the key perform it on the message value https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/hoistfield.html

Comment: I still think joining the data would provide better results, assuming one topic acts as a "lookup table", or your have those two messages within a short time-window